# Howt o remove minus character in multiple occurences in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I would like to remove a minus character before different numbers in a chain.

1. What I currently have

> Percentage="-10000000000.00"
> Percentage="-999999.00"
> Percentage="-100000.00"
> Percentage="-52222222.00"

2. Expected

> Percentage="10000000000.00"
> Percentage="999999.00"
> Percentage="100000.00"
> Percentage="52222222.00"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Answer (score 0):

Use Find and Replace (Ctrl + H)

So find: `="-`

Replace with `="`

[image: the Power of Replace]

Should then give you want you want based on your input / output cases listed.

Answer (score 0):

I found this one:

```
search: Percentage="-(\d+\.\d+)"
replace: Percentage="$1"
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following find and replace in regex mode:

```
Find:    Percentage="-(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)"
Replace: Percentage="$1"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can search for the following regex with a lookahead pattern that matches a minus character that is followed by a digit:

```
-(?=\d)
```

And replace it with nothing.